# Producing multiple odds ratios in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a data set that is looking at the frequency of a categorical outcome (let's call the levels O1, O2, and O3) for a categorical IV (levels I1, I2, I3, I4). Is there a way to have SPSS calculate odds ratios for each outcome category (example: O1 versus [O2 and O3]) for each level of the IV versus all the other levels (example: I1 versus [I2 and I3]). Basically I want odds ratios for O1 versus not O1 in I1 versus not I1, then O1 versus not O1 in I2 versus not I2, so on and so forth. I know I could just recode the data each time but it would be nice to have syntax that would do that for me.

Comment: You'll need to clarify the question - how does the data look like and what are you trying to do

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have frequency data of an outcome and the frequency of the outcome not happening for multiple groups. For each group I have columns for frequency of outcome happened and outcome didn't happen. For each group I want the odds ratio of event happening compared to the sum of all the other groups. Example: Group1 happened=16, Group1 didnt happen=88, sum of happened for groups 2-5= 87, and sum of didnt happen for groups 2-5=24. So OR=1.513. Is there a way to have SPSS go through each possible combination (Group2 vs [Group1+Groups3-5; Group3 vs [Groups1-2+Groups 4-5], etc)?

Comment: this is somewhat clearer but please describe the structure of your data so we can point you to the right method

Comment: Column 1 is a categorical variable called Group with group names 1-8, column 2 is a categorical variable called FreqYes with frequencies of event happened, column 3 is a categorical variable called FreqNo with frequencies of event didn't happen, and column 4 is a categorical variable called GroupTotal with the total number of observations in each group (FreqYes + FreqNo). Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate your outcome ratio you need to have available, for each group, the total of all the other groups:

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=
  /FreqYesTot FreqNoTot = SUM(FreqYes FreqNo).
COMPUTE FreqYesOthrgrps = FreqYesTot - FreqYes.
COMPUTE FreqNoOthrgrps = FreqNoTot - FreqNo.
COMPUTE FreqBothOthrgrps = FreqYesOthrgrps + FreqNoOthrgrps.
```

Comment: Thanks. And to get the odds ratios with 95% CI and p-values?

Comment: I suggest you mark this question as solved and start a new one for the CI and P-values.